# Next.js _middleware is send to browser

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

For reasons of trying, I created a small _middleware.ts that should get some user information based on the current session of the user.

However, I imported a prisma (ORM) client and want to load the users' data, but when loading the page in the browser I get the following error message:

`Error: PrismaClient is unable to be run in the browser.`

I thought that the _middleware only runs in the browser and I'm a bit surprise that it get's send to the client.

Is there a way to solve/prevent this from happening?

**Edit:**

One possible solution I found is configuring webpack to not include the "_middleware" in the front-end bundle. But it feels like a workaround and creates other bugs.

**Edit2:**

I also found this command in nextjs:

```
// Errors from the middleware are reported as client-side errors
// since the middleware is compiled using the client compiler
```

Could the compilation using the client compiler be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is only about `PrismaClient` you could do

```
if (typeof window === "undefined") {
.. initialize prisma
}
```

I would not try to modify default next behavior from a maintenance/upgrade perspective.